# Running tcpdump inside bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to get some numbers from tcpdump inside a shell script and print that number.

Here is my script

```
while true
do
{
 b=`tcpdump -n -i eth1 | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $10}'`
echo $b
}
done
```

When I execute this script, I get this

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

Is there anything special I need to do to capture tcpdump o/p inside shell script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `tcpdump` runs forever (or until it's interrupted by Control-C or something similar). The

```
b=`tcpdump ...`
```

construct runs until `tcpdump` exits... which is never ... and *then* puts its output into $b. If you want to capture the output from a single packet, you can use `tcpdump -c1 ...` (or `-c5` to capture groups of 5, or similar). Alternately, you could let it run forever but capture its output one line at a time with a `while read` loop (although you need to use `tcpdump -l` to prevent excessive buffering):

```
tcpdump -l -n -i eth1 | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $10}' | while read b; do
    echo $b
done
```

I'm not entirely sure what your script is supposed to do, but I see some other issues. First, unless your version of `tcpdump` is much more consistent than mine, printing the 10th comma-delimited field of each packet will *not* get you anything meaningful. Here's some sample output from my computer:

```
00:05:02:ac:54:1e
1282820004:1282820094
90
73487384:73487474
1187212630:1187212720
90
90
host


2120673524
```

Second, what's the point of capturing the output into a variable, then printing it?  Why not just run the command and let it output directly? Finally, `echo $b` may garble the output due to word splitting and wildcard expansion (for example, if $b happened to be "*", it would print a list of files in the current directory). For this reason, you should double-quote variables when you use them (in this case, `echo "$b"`).

Comment: To elaborate, i am trying to capture or print whenever ack number is greater than a specific value. For example,  if I do, tcpdump -n -i eth1 '(tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-ack)' | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $10}' , it only displays ack numbers. What I would really like to do is to find if my ack number is equal to , lets say , 1024 and print a message , like, found ack number. That is my goal and not sure how I can accomplish that in live tcpdump flow.

Comment: Ah, if you restrict it like that you're more likely to get consistent results. In that case, I'd think the `while read` loop would be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am trying something like this. Basically, printing ack numbers between 19000 and 20000.                            tcpdump -n -i eth1 '(tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-ack) and (src host 192.168.2.1)' | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $10}' | while read b; do echo $b | awk '{ if ($1 > 19000 && $1 < 20000) print $1 }' ; done

Comment: The above command does seem to work for lower values, meaning, if i capture ack numbers between 19000 and 20000. However, if I try between 400000000 and 4200000000 (because ack numbers can be as big as 2 ^ 32), I dont get any output even though i know ack numbers that big are getting generated by my traffic. reason could be echo $b might not be able to keep everything in buffer until it is displayed.. not sure if there is any other solution for this scaling  test.

Comment: The TCP sequence number is only a 32-bit field, so unless tcpdump infers large values from watching it wrap around I wouldn't expect it to ever go past 2^32. Also, if all you are doing in the loop is echo each like to an awk command, you can skip the shell loop entirely, and pipe from one awk command to the other: `tcpdump -l -n -i eth1 '(tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-ack) and (src host 192.168.2.1)' | awk -F'[, ]' '{print $10}' | awk '{ if ($1 > 19000 && $1 < 20000) print $1 }'` (It's also probably easy to combine the awk commands, but I'm not confident enough in awk...)

Answer (score 0):

It's been so long since this question was asked but the simplest way to accomplish the goal of what the script was intending to catch would be to simply record a pcap matching only the packets you're interestedin seeing; as an example, to write a pcap file consisting only of packets where the ack flag is set and the acknowledgment number is a value between 19000 and 20000:

```
tcpdump -c2500 -iany 'tcp[8:4]>=19000&&tcp[8:4]<=20000&&tcp[13]&16!=0' -Uw./TCP_ACKs.pcap
```